# PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgbouncer

I have 2 servers(A, B).
I am running rails app in A and db in B.
In server B, I have pgbouncer and postgresql running.

When I run 200 threads in A, I am getting that issue even though I increased pgbouncer max client connection to 500. And pgbouncer pool_mode is session.
Postgresql pool is 100.

I also increased db pool to 500 in server A.

How can I avoid this issue and run 200 threads without any issue?

Later, I've updated code. Dropped pgbouncer and use postgresql directly.
Created 2 new threads which do db operation and other threads don't do db operation anymore.
And while threads run, I was monitoring active connections. It keeps 3 active.
But at the end of threads, I got this issue.
I showed connections pool status using ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat

```
{:size=>500, :connections=>4, :busy=>3, :dead=>0, :idle=>1, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this issue?

Comment: Anything in the PG logs?

Comment: 2020-10-30 07:57:45.808 UTC [15779] LOG C-0x55f2c78d3520: saveatrain_production/saveatrain@13.94.118.240:35910 closing because: client close request (age=113s)
2020-10-30 07:57:48.636 UTC [15779] LOG stats: 690 xacts/s, 705 queries/s, in 94591 B/s, out 232456 B/s, xact 913 us, query 870 us, wait 0 us
2020-10-30 07:57:50.990 UTC [15779] LOG C-0x55f2c78d1ae0: saveatrain_production/saveatrain@13.94.118.240:59996 closing because: client close request (age=782s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged db instance and app instance.
That works.
I am still not sure if it's db version issue or postgresql remote access issue.
In my opinion, it's remote access issue.